# Casperjs Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

```
casper.on("page.initialized", function(casp){
   this.echo("Initialized...");
   casper.evaluate(function(){     window.sessionStorage.setItem('authorization','xxxxxxx');
     window.sessionStorage.setItem('_USER','xxxxx');
     window.sessionStorage.setItem('USERNAME','xxxxx');
     window.sessionStorage.setItem('INTERNAL','xxxx');
   }); 
 }; 


  casper.test.begin('1: Asserting casperjs is working', 2, function suite(test) {
      test.assertEquals(true, true);
      test.assert(true);
      test.done();
  });

 casper.test.begin('starting at /', 5, function suite(test
   var starting = Date.now();

   casper.start();

   casper.open("xxxxx",function() {
     test.assertHttpStatus(200);
     var session = this.evaluate(function(){
      return JSON.stringify(window.sessionStorage);
      }); 
     this.echo("SESSION: ", session);
   }); 

   casper.then(function(){
     this.wait(10000, function(){this.echo("WAITED!");});
     this.echo(this.getHTML('body'));
     try{
       casper.waitFor(function check() {
         return this.evaluate(function() {
             var quotes = document.getElementById('quoteBody').children.length > 1;
             this.echo("QUOTES", quotes);
              return true;
           }); 
       }, function then() {
         // ending timer
         var ending = Date.now();
         var totalt = (ending - start) / 3600;
         test.assertFalsy(function(){
           return totalt >= 10.0;
         }, "loading asserting total time passed");
         this.echo("total time: ", totalt);
         // tests
         test.assertEval(function(){
           return document.querySelectorAll('#quotesBody tr').length > 1;
         }); 
         //this.echo(this.getHTML('body'));
         this.assertTitle("xxxxx", "title match");
       }); 
     } catch (e){
       this.echo(e);
     }   
      }); 

      casper.run(function() {
       test.done();
      }); 
 });
```

I've tried wrapping the `test.done()` in a timeout but I can't get passed the endless `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL...` warnings. The `document.getElementById('quoteBody').children.length > 1;` works in the browser, but is not returning true and triggering the waitTimeout event. It is after this event is emitted that I get the warnings. I tried waiting much longer than `10000` for loading to no avail. I was able to get some good advice from @Artjom B to get my script off the ground, but this seemingly perennial phantom bug is adding noise to my logs and the `waitFor` if returned falsy should not present any `Unsafe` errors.

**edit**

I think I can fix my script if the warnings weren't completely polluting my output. I've tried web-security=no flags -- didn't work. downgrade to phantom 1.9.2 from 1.9.8? I understand 1.9.8 is a little buggy and many people are having this issue. I'm much more concerned about how to get rid of the noise for now.

Comment: Please disregard the "Unsafe..." warnings. They are printed during exit and don't have any influence on your script. Instead, you should make clear what the issue is with your script. Show some outputs, describe the behavior and tell what needs to happen.

Answer (score 0):

still looking for solution

```
"phantomjs": "^1.9.9"
```

for casperJs

```
casperjs --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 test  run.js
```